# Search a particular item between Two Custom List

Tags: linq

I have 2 lists of type `List<Course>`

- `List<Course> courseTakenFilterListByStatus`
- `List<Course> TakenCoursesNotApplied`

I want to find if `courseTakenFilterListByStatus.Id` is present in the `TakenCoursesNotApplied` list. Then I need to update Boolean property `IsRequired` to `TRUE`. If the value will not be there the property should be set to `False`.

Comment: please give us some code of what you have tried already

Comment: Are Id and Required properties of the course class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what it has to do with linq.

couldn't you just do the following:

```
foreach (Course course in courseTakenFilterListByStatus){

      // Possibility 1
      course.IsRequired = TakenCoursesNotApplied.Contains(course);
      // Possibility 2
      course.IsRequired = TakenCoursesNotApplied.Any(c => c.Id == course.Id);

}
```

Don't know if i understodd the logic right. Possibly you have to negate the assigment.
HTH Tobi